# Pandas read_csv drop all lines after EOF

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading csv files into pandas with the usual pd.read_csv. this works all fine. however, most of my csv files have a row at the end which has "#EOD" as the first column value to indicate the last row of this table. there might be more rows after this with all "nan" values.

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv')

Out[1]: 
     A    B      C   D
0   C1    A    0.5   9
1   C2    A    0.2   1
2   C3    A    0.3   7
3   C4    B    0.2   4
4   #EOD  None nan   nan
5   *     None nan   nan
```

how can I drop the all rows after and including the "#EOD" row when reading in the csv? I dont know if its only 1 line or several lines after the "#EOD", it can be different from file to file.

Comment: Do you have other `nan` values in the csv files. I think simple `df.dropna(inplace=True)` should work because there are/will be `nan` values in the row containing `#EOD`.

Comment: yes can be many nan values so unfortunately, this doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - Find index of "#EOD" first and then slice.

```
df[:(df.query("A=='#EOD'")).index.item()]
    A  B    C    D
0  C1  A  0.5  9.0
1  C2  A  0.2  1.0
2  C3  A  0.3  7.0
3  C4  B  0.2  4.0
```

Or use `iloc` for general

```
df[: df[df.iloc[:,0]=="#EOD"].index[0]]
```

Comment: thanks. i was looking for an even more generic way as first column name can be different. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Get the index of the last wanted row and use it in a slice. (`.loc` slices include the end label, unlike python list-slicing)

```
idx = df.loc[df.iloc[:, 0].shift(-1).eq('#EOD')].index[0]
df.loc[:idx, :]
```

Comment: thanks. i was looking for an even more generic way as first column name can be different. any ideas?

Comment: @RichieV  Use `iloc` instead of `loc` so you can avoid `shift` then - `df.iloc[:idx, :]`